# Why do I get "The required URI is not a valid FTP-Command."

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I tried to use an example from Microsoft C#. [The link is here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However I now get the error as seen in the title (thought its translated from danish to english)

The line that it says to have problem at is:
`Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();`

(of course in the real code its my actual adress and pass.)

(Also I tried to create a folder and it worked)

The whole function is:

```
public static void MakeFTPFile(string FileName,string[] Lines)
{
    string sourcefilepath = "";
    string ftpurl = "ftp://ftpAdress";
    string ftpusername = "Username";
    string ftppassword = "Pass";

    FileName += ".txt";

    if (!File.Exists(FileName))
    {
        // Create a file to write to. 
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(FileName))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Lines[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileName);
    string ftpfullpath = ftpurl;
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.UseBinary = true;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(FileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();

    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ftpstream.Close();
}
```

Comment: What's the `ftpAdress`?

Comment: Yes uploadding file and the ftpAdress is the url to connect. The host url